# I need an in progress workflow to cancel if an item is modified so a new workflow can be initiated

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, pause

I need a workflow to check if an item has been updated within the past hour because I need a dashboard to flag items that have not been updated in the past hour. I tried to have a pause for duration 1 hr workflow start when created/modified, and then set a choice field to "Over One Hour".  If the item is modified before the hour, I need the time to restart without setting the choice field to "Over One Hour".  Does anyone have any solutions with SharePoint Designer?